# How to flatten pdf form after filling pdf filed's and save as non editable in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, pdf, adobe

Here the detail explanation:-

**Requirement:**

I have one PDF file and after filling form fields in the in that pdf I need to take print of that file and making it as the noneditable form in **React Native**

**Problem**

I am able to fill the pdf form fields programmatically but I am facing problem while flattening that file, and while printing that file also.

- **In Android,** PDF become white pages nothing is shown in each page.
- **In iOS,** field form values are not present while printing.

**Exception:**

Any Pure javascript(it should work in mobile) or **React Native** library will make editable PDF to flatten PDF.

Any method to print PDF after filling the form fields in React Native

**What I Tried**

I used [Pdfform.js](https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js) to fill the pdf form fields I can display it in [PDFjs](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any working solution to how to flatten programmatically in using javascript.

Comment: I don't know if this will help or not. But I had a similar problem with PDFs and I was working with the native mobile applications. My PDFs were printed fine when I installed the latest Adobe Acrobat in the android device and opened the PDF via it for printing. Also, printing has a lot to do with your printer drivers.  Is your PDF working fine when you transfer it to a desktop/laptop and try printing it from there?

Comment: Also, are you able to view in your mobile properly when you are rendering it via PDF.js?

Comment: @AbhasTandon, am able to view it in PDF.js web view in mobile but it not working for print.

Comment: You can try converting the PDF into an image and then back to PDF https://gist.github.com/imolorhe/f8794d3bb55e1a8065b23bcd0efeebe1 https://parall.ax/products/jspdf